# Is there a way in python to make a list with the minimum weight of each path between two data points without taking too much time?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization, python

I need to do the following thing:

Given a fully connected graph I want to calculate the path similarity between each pair of vertices.

To do that for a pair ($i$, $j$) we need to take the the maximum value of the following set: {minimum edge weight for each path : where the path starts in $i$ and end in $j$.

Obviously it is possible to consider all paths between $i$ and $j$, take the minimum edge weight of each one, then take the maximum between these minimal edges weights, but this takes too long for a large graph. Does anyone know a way to do this more quickly?

Comment: This sounds like the [widest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widest_path_problem) (or I am turned around in your definition...).

Comment: You are perfectly right. The widest path problem wants to find a path between two designated vertices in a weighted graph, maximizing the weight of the minimum-weight edge in the path. For me, I need the value of that maximization. Do you know any algorithm for finding it?

Comment: Eric, I did the algorithm, much for your help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hardest part is to compute, for each pair of vertices $(i,j)$, the minimal weight of a path from $i$ to $j$. There is an effective way to do that : what you need is a good old [Djikstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

Once you've got your function, say djikstra(i, j), that computes "minimum edge weight for each path : where the path starts in i and end in j", all you have to do is to take the maximum value thereof.
Say your vertices are indexed from 0 to n−1, you get the answer with  (don't forget to import itertools) :

```
answer = max(djikstra(i, j) for (i, j) in itertools.product(range(n), range(n)))
```

Comment: This finds the minimal cost path between two vertices.  It does not find any sort of maximum over the set of paths between those two vertices.

Comment: @EricTowers The hardest part of the OP's problem is to find the "minimum edge weight for each path". This is what the Djikstra's algorithm will compute. I should (and will) explain that indeed! :)

Comment: Thanks for your contributions! But it's not clear to me how to use the algorithm of finding the shortest path in the above problem. Could you help me understanding that?

Comment: @ChibiPeew Once you've got your function, say djikstra(i, j), that computes "minimum edge weight for each path : where the path starts in i and end in j", all you have to do is to take the maximum value thereof. Say your vertices are indexed from $0$ to $n - 1$, you get the answer with :

(don't forget to import itertools)
answer = max(dijkstra(i, j) for (i, j) in itertools.product(range(n), range(n)))

Comment: @OlivierRoche The information in your last comment is relevant to your answer, so you should edit it into your answer. Comments are just for temporary communications.

Comment: Guys, I did the algorithm, much for your help, thanks! The whole problem is solved by an application of Djikstra's algorithm.

Comment: @ChibiPeew please accept the answer (and upvote it) if it was helpful. ;)

Comment: Okay! Did it (: